# Overlaying thousands of points of a route from shapefile and dbf on google maps

Tags: postgis, shapefile, javascript, google-maps, dbf

I have to overlay thousands of points(data taken every second) of a route from shapefile and related data for each points in dbf. I have to show point related data in a popup on click of a point. I will be getting few shapefiles every day and overlay data of few of the shapefile on the map as per request. Over 2-3 years I will have multiple thousand shapefiles. I have tried two different approaches as follows.

Parse the shapefile with PHP classes at request time with pointer of shapefile in database table (postgres db) and pass all the data to browser in JSON. It becomes very slow in overlaying points on google maps as I zoom in on to the route.

Another approach I used is storing each points(long/lat) with corresponding data from dbf as separate rows and connect my db(postgres) to geoserver. Using geoserver to serve data tile-by-tile. Making request to geoserver to show cached point data on click of a point, but then I am worried about dealing with millions of rows (thousands of points of a shapefile with multiple thousand shapefile over couple of years) in postgres table.

Do you have any suggestions for some other approach or improving one of the current approaches?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Here you seem to be asking for a small project review which I think makes it too broad.  I think you should ask about just one of your approaches in more detail and tell us precisely what you tried, and where you are stuck.  I think that this would need to involve you presenting a code snippet.